# parallel option for predict.glmmTMB

Tags: parallel-processing, predict, glmmtmb

a glmmTMB model can be parallelised like this:

```
example <- data.frame("c_value"=runif(10), "pre1"=1:10, "pre2"=rnorm(10), "place"=factor(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]))

my.model <- glmmTMB(c_value~pre1 + pre2 + (1|place), example, 
                    family=beta_family(link="logit"), control = glmmTMBControl(parallel=6))
```

and I can predict like this:

```
newd <- data.frame("pre1"=3, "pre2"=rnorm(10), "place"=factor(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]))
prediction <- predict(my.model, newd)
```

but is there a way to parallelise the prediction? This doesn't work:

```
faster.prediction <- predict(my.model, newd, control = glmmTMBControl(parallel=6))
```

Comment: Can we have a little more detail please?  How big is your data set? How long does the prediction take?